# Implement search in multiple tables in database with ASP .NET MVC

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, search

I have a question about implementing search functionality. I have a table which contains 2 user id's and details of transaction between them (title, date, description, etc.). I want to allow user to search transactions by any of these criteria (so typing "Mike salary 2013" would result in transactions from 2013 with Mike, which title or description contained word "salary").

This can be accomplished by joining required tables, creating a search string and filtering every input word by that string, but what concerned me, was that Transaction table is designed to have ultimately millions of rows - so joining multiple tables + string operations from database's side could be slow.

My another idea was to create separate column for search string - that string would be created with creation of transaction and would contain all necessary information. The problem is when user decides to change his/her name (users can do that form their "Profile" page). The search strings in all transactions assigned to that user would be outdated.

So here's my question: is it better to search all entries and update search strings after user changes their name (it would be costly, but users don't change their names often) or give up on this whole "search string column" idea and do it with old-fashioned joins? Or maybe there is another option?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Full Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). It actually combines both of your ideas. You can run FTS queries on multiple columns and multiple tables. Behind the scenes, FTS uses an index, which is similar to your "search string column" idea.

Comment: But can i use it with LINQ to Entities?